# How to reference the already exisiting (created with GCP console) shared VPC and its subnets using terraform in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Need to refer an already existing shared VPC and subnets in service project using terraform. Is there a way to do it. Just repeating , the shared VPC is created by web ui and we need to refer it in terraform while creating a resource in service project.

Comment: What about this sample ...

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_shared_vpc_host_project.html#example-usage

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But my shared VPC already exists and it is not managed by terraform. This sample does not solve it.

Comment: What about this one ... https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_shared_vpc_service_project.html